# Retriving DVB data tables using IPSITables

Tags: c++, video-streaming, directshow, dvb

I am trying to extract the EIT table using the non-deprecated interface IPSITables from a DVB stream.
I have not found documentation about how to use the getTable method, apart from the msdn documentation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd694841%28v=vs.85%29.aspx.

The problem is that I don't know how to get the *dwHashedVer [in]* parameter (Hash value that identifies the table contents).

Has anyone used this interface before?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a read  of the [ETSI 301-192 spec](http://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_en/301100_301199/301192/01.04.02_60/en_301192v010402p.pdf). The microsoft documentation or this API is almost non-existant. I am taking a shot in the dark here, so please bear with me. In table 8.4.4 there is a field `platform_id_hash` which is generated from the platform id. The means for getting this hash is also explained in the spec.  The platform id is defined as

```
platform_id: This is a 24 bit field which serves as a label to identify a given IP/MAC platform. Allocation of the value
of this field are found in the TR 101 162 [21].
```

Hope this helps